# Does high APC fragmentation matter?

Tags: apc

I'm seeing a high amount of fragmentation on APC (>80%) but performance actually seems pretty good. I've [read another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292330/apc-cache-fragmentation-on-wordpress-site) that advises disabling object caching in wordpress / w3tc, but I wonder if the reduction in fragmentation is better than the performance boost of caching the objects in the first place.

[image: cache fragmentation]
[image: apc settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragmented APC is still a few times better than without APC, so please don't deactivate APC.
Increase your memory instead. With more memory APC will fragment lot less. This will be healthier for APC itself.
APC itself has no "defragmentation" process. You could restart yout http service or call apc_clear_cache() in an php script. But beware of the performance impact for the next minutes when your cache will be rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

Fragmentation on disk based systems is important because the head physically has to move to each location to read it. The APC cache though by definition is in Random Access Memory so the penalty for having to read a different location is in the order of a couple of CPU cycles, ie negligible unless you're seriously loading the CPU. And if you're doing that then you have bigger problems.

Also don't assign too much RAM to APC. You really want 5-10% more than the maximum possible cache. Any more is a waste of precious RAM.

I think it is misleading to put fragmentation as a metric on the APC monitor page as it's just not that important and people worry unduly. Running with highly fragmented APC is orders of magnitude better than running without it at all.